# Setting up a sharer

Tags: facebook-like, share

I'm setting up a sharer on my site pages, and i've found different links for using the sharer :

- share.php
- sharer.php
- sharer/sharer.php

Which one is the right one to use ?
In the [Facebook doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) it says the second one, but only with the third was i able to share to a fan page (no linked profile).

Is there a difference between sharing on a profile or on a page ?

Thanks.

Comment: Facebook says sharer is deprecated at the very top of the documentation link you have above.  Please don't use it!

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference among them, it is just their looks and size that is changed using the property `type`.

Comment: You're talking about the different share buttons ? It's not about that but about the url for building a custom share button, like described at the end of this page : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ (Creating your own share url)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend against:

"The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and will no longer be supported.
Please use the Like button whenever possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps."

So, instead of waking up with an nonfunctional share button, you'd be better off with a like button, or implementing a share button from scratch using the JS SDK.

Also, I can tell you for a fact that most of the people would share on their own wall rather than on a page.

Comment: I was wondering if it is juste the share button that is deprecated, or all the share functions. It is not really clear.
I think that i can't post the same way on a page with a like button.
My client is an institution so they only have a page and no profile, they have no other choice than to share/post on their page.

Answer (score 0):

The correct one to use is sharer/sharer.php

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.org" target="_blank">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/